# SwiftUI StateObject is initialized twice. How to ensure it's initialized only once?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have ProjectView with ProjectViewModel. ProjectViewModel contains some heavy logic inside, which should be initialized only once. However ProjectViewModel.init is called twice. I see it while debugging. Have you ever faced such an issue? Here is my code:

```
    struct ProjectView: View {
        @StateObject private var viewModel: ProjectViewModel
        @StateObject private var tonalityViewModel: TonalityViewModel
        @StateObject private var tempoViewModel: TempoViewModel
    
        private init(viewModel: @escaping () -> ProjectViewModel) {
            _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel())
            let viewModel = _viewModel.wrappedValue
            _tonalityViewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel.createTonalityViewModel())
            _tempoViewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel.createTempoViewModel())
        }
    
        init(recording: RecordingFile) {
            self.init(viewModel: {
                ProjectViewModel(recording: recording)
            })
        }
    
        init(filePath: String?) {
            self.init(viewModel: {
                ProjectViewModel(filePath: filePath)
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why you are doing that heavy logic in initialization? You can make in `onAppear` as well, it work better.

Comment: I want to create ViewModel with parameter

Comment: Is it called twice for the same view instance or is it for two different instances?

Comment: Fo the same view instance

Comment: I still do not see any reason why you want do heavy logic in initialization! Your app would work the same and you would have no issue in `onAppear`

Comment: Don't initialize inside `init`. SwiftUI can reinitialize the `View` [at any time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app). Likely causes leaks too, people doing this with `@ObservedObject` mention them in SO. Custom `init()`s in SwiftUI `View`s are a bad idea in most instances.